# Cron vs APscheduler vs something else for 2 second interval

Tags: cron, apscheduler

I need to pull data from a serial connection at a fixed interval of 2 second with a piece of python code. The software is running on a Raspberry Pi 24/7.

As far as i see it, i have three options:

1. Start my python script as a service (with systemd) and use an APscheduler
2. Use a cron-job (possible?)
3. Use another solution

What is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's how you can do this job in [`apscheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def pull_data():
    print("code comes here")


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(pull_data, "interval", seconds=2)

scheduler.start()
```

**`apscheduler`** **also supports async code**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


async def pull_data():
    await print("code comes here")


scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(pull_data, "interval", seconds=2)

scheduler.start()
```

#### You can also do this job with lightweight python library [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/).

```
import time
import schedule


def pull_data():
    print("code comes here")


schedule.every(2).seconds.do(pull_data)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```